# jstl iteration error

Tags: java, jstl

I want to bind the value to dropdownlist, the value is retrieved from database.

I want the result supposed to be as below:

```
    <option value=Sick>Sick</option>                      
    <option value=Funeral>Funeral</option>                  
    <option value=Trip>Trip</option>                    
    <option value=Others>Others</option>
```

But now I get the result as below :

```
  <option value=Others>Others</option>
  <option value=Others>Others</option>
  <option value=Others>Others</option>
  <option value=Others>Others</option>
```

Here is my java code :

```
while(rs.next()){
    le.setReason(rs.getString("lr_name"));
    arrLeave.add(le);
}
request.setAttribute("arrLeave", arrLeave);
```

Here is my JSP :

```
<c:forEach items="${arrLeave}" var="arrLeave">
<option value=${arrLeave.reason}>${arrLeave.reason}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

What is the problem ? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only a single `le` class instance, so will get *n* copies of whatever the last reason was.

Create a new instance for each row in the result set:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    arrLeave.add(new Leave(rs.getString("lr_name")));
}
```

Comment: Sorry , I am new in JSP. But I have solved the problem ! Thanks you.

Comment: @user1154655 This wasn't a JSP issue, though; it's a basic Java thing: if you keep referencing the same object, you're modifying a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the same object and adding it to the list..

```
le.setReason(rs.getString("lr_name")) -> same object updated over all iteration
```

Initialize le using new operator before you set the reason..

```
<BeanName> le = new <BeanName>();
le.setReason(rs.getString("lr_name"));
```

Comment: Leave le = new Leave() this is the instance i created earlier , it means i have to create 1 more instance ?

Comment: @user1154655 ... You have to **create one for each row in the result set**.

Comment: @user1154655 Seriously? SKS already told you, I already told you. See updated answer.